# Cannot read property of object that I got from axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using a react useState hook to set an empty array state and then I use the useEffect to get some placeholder data with axios. After placing it I tried getting the object, but it keeps telling me postData[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhvJq.png) is undefined if I try to grab postData[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhvJq.png).body.

At first I thought its because it's an array, but when I use typeof it clearly says its an object. So I am very confused what's going wrong here. Did I fetch the data poorly or something?

Thanks in advance!

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function Home() {
  const [postData, setPostData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
      axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then(res => {
        setPostData(res.data);
      })
    }, [])


    console.log(typeof(postData[1]))
    console.log(postData[1])

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <h4 className="center">Home</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
              Unde, deleniti, amet iste ratione fugiat, dolorem aliquid adipisci aperiam rem iure provident ad? 
              Incidunt recusandae pariatur nisi quaerat corporis harum aperiam.</p>
        </div>
      );
    }

    export default Home;
```

EDIT:
I just saw I can post an image. So maybe this might help abit: First image is When I use console.log(postData[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhvJq.png), second image when I use console.log(postData[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhvJq.png).body

[image: When I use console.log(postData[1]]

[image: When I use console.log(postData[1].body]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209581/discussion-on-question-by-pgreat-cannot-read-property-of-object-that-i-got-from).

Answer (score 0):

Since the `axios.get` is async, it will show undefined when you try to check the change from inside of the function component, not in the hooks. If you want to see the response you can directly add to the success of `axios.get` like in the below code.

```
axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then(res => {
  setPostData(res.data);
  console.log(res.data);
})
```

if you want to be sure that `postData` is filled. You can check the below code.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(typeof(postData[1]));
    console.log(postData[1]);
}, [postData])
```

Comment: I get what you mean. But If I console.log postdata[0] I get the object I need. With properties attached to it. However when I combine .body to it, it just goes haywire and says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined"